# Images published from GitHub Pages not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css, github

I am publishing some simple webpages (HTML, CSS, some JS) from my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/orlando21/product-showcase). When I display `index.html` in Chrome (55.0.2883.95, 64 bit) by clicking on the [URL linked in this repository](http://gregbabb.com/product-showcase/), the webpage is displayed, but as soon as I scroll down, the featured image disappears when it shouldn't.

The other working link is "Fees" at the top. Click on that, scroll up and down the page, and the featured image will similarly disappear.

I want to point out that I first published this repository/page in Nov. 2016 and the images all displayed fine. Recently I changed the domain name associated with the repo but normally wouldn't expect this to create issues. Also, when I simply zip and download the repo and open in Chrome locally, everything displays perfectly.

Lastly, this site works with CSS Grid so I have the appropriate flag enabled in Chrome. It's hard for me to understand why images suddenly don't display correctly using GitHub Pages!

**EDIT** Sorry if this question seems vague. Let me restate. Everything seems to initially load and display correctly in my browser. *The issue seems to be triggered by merely scrolling down the page*.
 
This code used to display correctly on GitHub Pages. I come back two months later and the same code doesn't work anymore. Image pathnames are all correct. It's evidently not a JS issue. Download the same code and it displays perfectly on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/cRNc9e6PrKE) I realized that one of my extensions was causing the page to disappear on scrolling. Specifically, I disabled the [Window Resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh) extension and the problem was solved.